# Samba - Edit permissions windows side

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, zfs

I am looking to be able to add domain users to folder permissions and change their access rights from the windows side. This control currently gives me an error message saying access is denied in regard to editing security information.

Some background - I am using a Ubuntu ZFS server with Samba, my samba shares are from my ZFS dataset mounts. Im not sure if this would effect the behaviour of permissions.

I have tried to set the owner of the folder I want Windows side control over to my user, but still get the 'Access is denied' message when I select apply.

I know these arent great details, so please ask for any additional information and I shall provide any required answers.

I am wondering whether it is an additional samba setting i require to allow this, or a windbind setting, or a zfs setting. I have so many different things I could address Im finding it hard to find which is the problem. So was hoping for some ideas and help on how this can be enabled.

Thanks in advance.